# Loading an HTML file into a PHP variable?

Tags: php, html

I want to load contents from external HTML sites via GET.

PHP:

```
<?php
 $content = file_get_contents('template/' . $_GET['l'] . "/" + $_GET['n'] . ".html");
?>
```

So I want to call this page: (page root)/template/html/1.html

Now if I do so by adding the parameters within the URL (file.php?l=html&n=1), I get nothing displayed. Why is this?

Comment: Have you tried hardcoding it and see if that works? Your snippet does not "echo" anything so that might be it too.

Comment: @FabienWarniez I do <?php echo $content; ?> in my main PHP file.

Comment: You are using `+` instead of `.` to concatenate your strings. Use `.`

Comment: @Pekka웃 Changed it, still doesn't work.

Comment: Do an `echo 'template/' . $_GET['l'] . "/" + $_GET['n'] . ".html"` and see whether the path really is correct. Are you sure you are in the right directory?

Comment: Appearently it calls 01.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.` instead of `+` to concatenate.